# Integration Wirecloud with IDM Keyrock

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to replicate the [installation guide](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_guide/#integration-with-the-idm-ge) to integrate [Wirecloud 1.0.1](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/releases/tag/1.0.1) with the latest version of IDM Keyrock.
I'd like to understand if the guide in the documentation is valid again for this version of WC.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: What are your problems? Specify how your configuration files are and the problems you are facing.

Comment: I followed the guide but I can't land from Wirecloud to the Keyrock login page. I always go to the page `http://<my domain>/login/fiware/?`I can't solve this.

Comment: We cannot help if we do not know the configuration and the code you are using. We need details.

Comment: I'm using the Wirecloud version 1.0.1, I've followed all the steps in the this [guide](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_guide/#integration-with-the-idm-ge), installing by **pip** the `social-auth-app-django`, editing the `settings.py` and the `urls.py`. The result is the page `http://<my domain>/login/fiware/?` when I click the **Sign in** button in the WC homepage.

Comment: If I understood your problem, you are telling that always you're going to the fiware login page, right? I think this is the correct behaviour, since you have to put your fiware credentials to get authenticated and receive a valid OAuth2 token. With this token, you can access the protected service (Wirecloud).

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the linked documentation is not valid for WireCloud v1.0.1, you linked to the `latest` branch of the documentation, that is the documentation for the development version of WireCloud.

The documentation on how to configure WireCloud v1.0.1 to use the IdM can be found in this [link](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/installation_guide/#integration-with-the-idm-ge).

> We know that is not clear that the `latest` branch is the one used for document the development version, but Read The Docs does not allow us to rename (or we do not know yet how to do it) this branch using a more meaningful name (e.g. `develop`). The default branch is `stable` (pointing to the documentation of the latest stable version of WireCloud) but it has proben to not be enough. We have created a [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/317) for improving this aspect.

Comment: Thank you for your help!